# Where can I download the last default.style for osm2pgsql?

Tags: style, osm2pgsql, download, default

Where can I download the last default.style for osm2pgsql?

I get `http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/export/osm2pgsql/default.style - this directory does not exist` when I try to download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file seems to have moved. Have a look here:

https://raw.github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/master/default.style